# Where are the junit tests for Google Guava libraries?

Tags: java, junit, guava

Could someone please provide a link to junit tests for the Google Guava library ? I downloaded the source but that didn't come with the junit source files .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in the [source tree](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk#trunk/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/base) which you can [check out](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/checkout) with Subversion.

Comment: honestly, that's about 5% of them and they probably don't even run.

Comment: It is THE major issue that is holding up release 10, like it did release 9, 8, 7, 6, and 5 before it; only difference is this time we're really not going to cop out on it.